# How to back up your SharePoint 2013 On-Premises site to an external drive

Tags: 2013

I need to back up my SharePoint site, but I do not have access to Powershell cmdlets. I do not see any options for backing up in the Site Settings page.

Answer (score 0):

Under site settings, I see save site as template option.
Try using this and make sure to include content whilesaving site as template

Comment: This doesn't help me. Most of my sites have SharePoint Server Publishing enabled already, which disables the 'Save Site as Template' option, and this doesn't have much to do with backing up the entire site.